# Can I do a "before hook" on rspec get / post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write tests for an API which requires an hmac signature on each request.

```
describe Api::V2::HmacController, :type => :controller do
  render_views

  it 'GET' do
    get :index, timestamp: Time.now.to_i, format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end

end
```

I would like to add

```
request.env['x-api-key'] = API_KEY
request.env['x-api-hmac'] = "Encode"(API_SECRET, "parameters of the request")
```

to each request.

I'm open to any type of solution.

**Question:** How can I wedge a hook after the request has been formed, but hasn't sent?

I'm thinking of overwriting rspec get / post method, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from in the block

`request.headers['x-api-key'] = API_KEY`

You shouldn't set access the request headers through the env.

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers)